# "As" as a relative pronoun

Tags: sentence-structure, relative-clauses, as

> This weighed about 50% more than the first edition, reflecting my
>   growing discovery that there was, so to speak, more grammar around
>   than I had first thought. The third edition incorporated further
>   improvements, **as** has the current fourth.

Might I trouble you to tell me whether 'as' denotes 'further improvements' or not?

My parsing is:

> The third edition incorporated **further improvements**. And **it**
>   has the current forth.

Comment: It means the third edition has the same further improvements of the current fourth.

Comment: The third edition incorporated further improvements, like the current fourth has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not a pronoun, relative or otherwise.

Think of this as two sentences:

> The third edition incorporated further improvements. The fourth edition incorporate further improvements as well

The *as well* could instead be *in like manner*, which denotes not only that it also had improvements, but that they were done in a similar way.

Or consider an equivalent formulation that has less extraneous details:

> You have been to university, as have I.

Where you have a SVO sentence, it can be extended with such an additional clause specifying an additional subject for which the same sentence could be said.

> Dogs have four legs.

Subject is *dogs*, verb is *have*, and subject is *four legs*.

> Dogs have four legs, as have cows.

Cows, like dogs, have four legs.

> The students in my day wanted to change the world.

Subject is *students*, qualified by "in my day", verb is *wanted*, object is *to change the world*.

> The students in my day wanted to change the world, as do students today.

Students today also want to change the world.

The verb in the "*as*" clause is an auxiliary of some sort, and depends on the original verb and object of the main clause, and the tense of both the main clause and the *as* clause.

So, what this really means is that *as has* in your example might be thought of as relative (though not a pronoun), and its antecedent is *incorporated further improvements*.